# ggplot function doesn't work when to compare with qplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

This R code with `ggplot` function does nothing but when I want to do it with `qplot()` it works. What is the problem in it?

```
qplot(carat,data=diamonds,geom="histogram")
ggplot(diamonds,aes(x=carat),geom_bar(),stat_bin(),binwidth=2)
```

Comment: you need to `+` the `geoms` together: e.g. `ggplot(data=diamonds, aes(x=caret)) + geom_bar()`

Comment: Thank you very much tospig,I forgot it

Answer (score 4):

`geom_bar` and `stat_bin` should be out of `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds,aes(x=carat)) +
  geom_bar() + 
  stat_bin()
```

or more simply

```
ggplot(diamonds,aes(x=carat)) + geom_histogram()
```

you can add `binwidth` as an argument to `geom_histogram` (or `stat_bin`)

Comment: Thank you very much Pascal,I forgot it

Comment: or more simply `ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat)) + geom_histogram()`

Comment: @mnel  Feel free to edit.

Comment: Thank you for adding this as CW! :)